# Height constraint animation 'jumping'

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uicontrol

I've been creating my own UIControl subclass for use in my tweak [iDunnoU](https://github.com/jacobcxdev/iDunnoU). I've finished the UIControl, with the exception of the expand/collapse animation. The issue with this animation is that it 'jumps' down/up when expanding/collapsing, instead of fanning out smoothly like my original mockup (see below).

I have uploaded the code to a GitHub repository, found [here](https://github.com/jacobcxdev/iDunnoUMenuButton). The code for adding the control to the superview can be found [here](https://github.com/jacobcxdev/iDunnoUMenuButton/blob/master/iDunnoUMenuButton/ViewController.swift#L38-L54), the code for setting up the height constraint can be found [here](https://github.com/jacobcxdev/iDunnoUMenuButton/blob/master/iDunnoUMenuButton/iDUMenuButton.swift#L92-L94), and the code for animating the height constraint can be found [here](https://github.com/jacobcxdev/iDunnoUMenuButton/blob/master/iDunnoUMenuButton/iDUMenuButton.swift#L45-L48).

[image: Mockup]
[image: iDunnoUMenuButton]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIView.animate()` can be a little tricky -- you need to call `.layoutIfNeeded()` on the correct view.

Replace your `isExpanded / didSet` in `iDUMenuButton` class with this:

```
var isExpanded = false {
    didSet {
        if isExpanded != oldValue {
            if isExpanded {
                becomeFirstResponder()
                let haptics = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .rigid)
                haptics.impactOccurred()
            }
            guard let sv = self.superview else {
                // shouldn't happen, but let's be thorough
                fatalError("Self must have a superview!!!")
            }
            // not needed
            //self.layoutIfNeeded()
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.heightConstraint.isActive = !self.isExpanded

                // call .layoutIfNeeded() on self's superview
                //self.layoutIfNeeded()
                sv.layoutIfNeeded()

                self.layer.shadowOpacity = self.isExpanded ? 1 : 0
                self.buttons.forEach { $0.setBadgeHidden(hidden: !self.isExpanded, animated: true) }
            }
            delegate?.menuButton(self, isExpandedDidUpdate: isExpanded)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been stuck on this for a while, so I'm really glad it's fixed!